# Get Description From Reference Table by ID

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, linq-to-sql

I have two SQL Server tables - `PhoneNumbers` and `PhoneLineTypes`.  `PhoneNumbers` has a foreign key `PhoneLineTypeID` that references `PhoneLineTypes.ID`.

Visual Studio created classes for both tables but the `PhoneNumber` class only has an `int` field for `PhoneLineTypeID` and not a field of type `PhoneLineType`.

My problem is that I want the string description of the phone line type, which would come from `PhoneLineTypes`, but I only have the int `PhoneLineTypeID` from `PhoneNumbers` (instead of `1` i want `"Fax"`).  I ultimately want to bind a WPF ComboBox to that value but since it doesn't exist in the class I don't know what to bind to.

Comment: I used existing tables created in SSMS and used the "LINQ to SQL Classes" template, not EF.

Comment: It's a reference though. The Foreign Key is there so you have a value that you can then perform a look up on the other table with. Can you post the Linq/SQL query that you're using currently to pull the information?

Comment: I'm not using any LINQ queries.  The DataContext class VS created has an EntitySet<PhoneNumber> property.  I'm accessing that directly.

Comment: Exactly. If you were storing the string description for PhoneLineType in PhoneNumbers you wouldn't need another table; you'd just add it when you created an instance of a new PhoneNumber.  The point of having the foreign key is to allow you to bridge the data between the two entities.  While VS may have created the tables and the relationship it's up to you to make that work for you.  In this case, the query I posted as an answer below should reconcile the phonelinetype name with the Phonelinetype id that's stored in your phonenumber.

Answer (score 0):

You should create converters to convert the PhoneLineTypeID to whatever you need from PhoneLineTypes. There are a few tutorials on the net how to use converters, if you need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a stab in the dark here with this, (it would have been nice to see something like your query or code), but you'll need to join the PhoneNumbers and PhoneLineTypes tables in your query. Using Linq, (which I think you said you were using), you'd be looking at something like

```
var query = from number in PhoneNumbers
        join phoneType in PhoneLineTypes
        on numbers.PhoneLineTypeID equals phoneType.ID
        select new{
            ID = number.PhoneLineTypeID,
            Name = phoneType.Description
        }
phoneComboBox.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
phoneComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
phoneComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "ID"
```

Like I said, it's hard to help more without filling in some blanks but hopefully this should put you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

With your foreign keys in place, you should be able to do the following

```
var query = from number in PhoneNumbers
            select number.PhoneLineTypes.PhoneLineType
```